In SQLDelight, do I have to add an EntityAdapter() for every Column that I use common types like AS Int?
I have a large database to migrate from an older version of sqldelight. It is part of a Kotlin Multiplatform app. I have done most of the leg work but it seems as if in the newer 2.0.2 version I have to add adapters by hand for every single table and column that has "AS Int":
E.g
fun getDatabase(
    driverFactory: DriverFactory,
    dbName: String,
    encryptionKey: String
): Database {
    val driver = driverFactory.createDriver(dbName, encryptionKey)
    return Database(
        driver = driver,
        FirstEntityAdapter = FirstEntity.Adapter(
aAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
bAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
cAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
eAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
fAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
gAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
hAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
iAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
jAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
kAdapter = IntColumnAdapter,
lAdapter = IntColumnAdapter).... LOTS more adapters each with lots of IntColumnAdapters.

This will mean a LOT of boiler plate. I'm wondering if I'm missing something. This seams like something that could easily be generated along with the rest of the SQLDelight generated code?

I found the answer to my question in the migration guide:
https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.2/upgrading-2.0/
"Some previously supported types now require an adapter. Adapters for primitive types are available in the app.cash.sqldelight:primitive-adapters:2.0.2 artifact. e.g. The IntColumnAdapter for doing INTEGER As kotlin.Int conversions."
This will mean a large amount of boilerplate added for the app I need to migrate, or I'll need to do it in code :-(
Hopefully this can added to a future release to be handled for the common types; Int, Float, etc...
